# Getting error as "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[null, null, null]" while creating user using Rest Assured

Tags: rest, rest-assured

```java
package Day8;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.github.javafaker.Faker;
public class CreateUser { 

    @Test
    void test_CreateUser()
    {
        Faker fake = new Faker(); 
        JSONObject  jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        jsonobj.put("Name", fake.name().fullName());
        jsonobj.put("Gender", "FeMale");
        jsonobj.put("email", fake.internet().emailAddress());
        jsonobj.put("Status", "active");
        
        String bearer_Token = "removed access token but valid token is there in my code";
        
        int id = given()
        .headers("Authorization","Bearer "+bearer_Token)
        .contentType("application/json")
        .body(jsonobj.toString())
        
        .when()
        .post("https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users")
        .jsonPath()
        .getInt("id");       
            System.out.println(id);         
    }   
}
```

Below output i got
I was expecting as user will create and will get successful response

`Actual Result : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[null, null, null]"`

Please help me, did lot of r&d but could not find solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: I found what you did wrong here:

- First: key in json is case-sensitive, you have to send exactly that server requires. `Name` -> `name`,  `Gender` -> `gender`, `Status` -> `status`
- Second: `id` is large number, it's out of range of `int`, use `long` instead.

Correct code would be:

```java
Faker fake = new Faker(); 
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
jsonobj.put("name", fake.name().fullName());
jsonobj.put("gender", "female");
jsonobj.put("email", fake.internet().emailAddress());
jsonobj.put("status", "active");

String bearer_Token = "your_token";

long id = given()
        .headers("Authorization","Bearer "+bearer_Token)
        .contentType("application/json")
        .body(jsonobj.toString())
        .when()
        .post("https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users")
        .jsonPath()
        .getLong("id");
System.out.println(id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Did as per your suggestion. But still getting null pointer exception.  
                                                                                                                                      
              "FAILED: Day8.CreateUser.test_CreateUser(org.testng.TestRunner@24313fcc)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "io.restassured.internal.common.path.ObjectConverter.convertObjectTo(Object, java.lang.Class)" is null"

Comment: Oh, I see, this because the value of `id` is out of range that `int` can hold. Easy fix is `getLong("[0].id")`. Already changed my anwser.